# Read a .csv file and put its content into a python list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file containing one column(places) containing various names of places.
I want to read this file and put its content into a python list.

I tried the below code:

`import pandas as pd
list=[]
df=pd.read_csv("File_Name")
for i in df:
  list.append(i)`

But this appends only the first term of the csv file into the list.
I know this is a minor syntax error but it would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just access your column and convert it to list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('File_Name')
my_list = df['Column_Name'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..
Just slightly edit your code. It will be 
pd.read_csv